# sap.m.Select: How to Get Item Text

Tags: sapui5

I have this code given below in view page:

```
<Select id="deptId" required="true">
    <core:Item key="1" text="Agri" />
    <core:Item key="2" text="Trade" />
    <core:Item key="3" text="Marketing" />
</Select>
```

I need to get value in Controller page. I added this code below:

```
department = this.getView().byId("deptId").getSelectedKey();
```

But all I am getting is key value like `1`, `2`, and `3` and not `"Agri"`, `"trade"` and `"Marketing"`.

I even tried adding `.getSelectedKey().getValue()` which is throwing an error.
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to get the selected Item control and get the text from that control.

```
var oItem = this.getView().byId("deptId").getSelectedItem();
var department = oItem.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation of sap.m.Select](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Select.html) you should go with `getSelectedItem()` instead of `getSelectedKey()`.